# how to have to modal with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've tried this plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/s902hdUIjKJo0h6u6k0l?p=preview

```
 angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function  ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
```

but it gives an error 
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: itemsProvider <- items

I want to have two buttons with  2 differents modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of syntax mistakes:
Updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/vgM5PLyVgluOeikGvVSA?p=preview

Changes made in JS:-

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
});



angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl2', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items2 = ['item12', 'item22', 'item32'];

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance2 = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent2.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl2',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items2: function () {
          return $scope.items2;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance2.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl2', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items2) {

  $scope.items2 = items2;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items2[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item2);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Comment: @toffd Hello, the best way to use bootstrap component with angular is http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ you can find all the small components like modal,Carousel ..etc with great explanation ,code and demo.
And please accept the answer and up vote if you are satisfied.

Comment: its ok ,but if you are satisfied please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my Angular Dialog Service, its built on top of ui.bootstrap's modal but offers prefabricated modals for errors, notifications, progression, confirmations and custom dialogs.  It allows you to set configuration as well in your application's config function using 'dialogsProvider' so you don't have to setup keyboard and backdrop settings everytime.  There's also support for using angular-translate and fontAwesome.

You can find it here: https://github.com/m-e-conroy/angular-dialog-service
or on bower.io.